# Turning off Spring warning logs using slf4j

Tags: java, spring

How will I be able to turn off the WARNING logs in Spring using slf4j? I've already placed this tag in the logback.xml but still, the log shows:

```
<logger name="org.apache.catalina.core" level="ERROR" />
```

Also under, pom.xml, I've specified the following spring dependencies to exclude commons-logging:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
</exclusions>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
<exclusions>
        <exclusion>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
</exclusions>
 </dependency>
```

Below is the sample WARNING messages that I received:

```
WARNING: Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd            http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang            http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security' must have even number of URI's.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:96)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:380)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:417)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.storeLocations(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2359)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:705)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3103)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:922)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting the right logger to error level try something like:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.beans.factory.xml" level="ERROR" />
```

If this isn't it, change your current logging pattern to include the logger name so that you can see which logger the warnings are coming from and then set it to error level:

```
<Pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger [%file : %line] %msg%n</Pattern>
```

Remember loggers are hierarchical, so setting the following will make all springframework loggers be at error level:

```
<logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR" />
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. This was not the logger/logger name... Do you know what are the other logging patterns that is displaying this warning? Thanks again!

Comment: thanks for the comment again. Btw, below are the entire contents of my logback.xml. Are there any conflicts?

Comment: <configuration>
 <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"</logger>
 <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
  <file>transactions.log</file>
  <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
   <Pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger [%file : %line] %msg%n</Pattern>
  </layout>
 </appender>

 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
   <Pattern>%msg%n</Pattern>
  </layout>
 </appender>

Comment: <root>
  <level value="ERROR" />
  <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
 </root>
</configuration>

Comment: hmm with the root level at error you should be seeing any warnings from any logger. The logging pattern i gave you should show the logger class and level you are getting the messages from are?

Comment: no it's still not displaying the logger class. Actually, it's the same pattern that i used initially. All it displays is the WARNING i posted above

Comment: I've updated my logback.xml again. BUt still, I can't view what logger is displaying the warning

Comment: <configuration>
 <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
  <file>transactions.log</file>
  <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
   <Pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger [%file:%line] %msg%n</Pattern>
  </layout>
 </appender>

 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
   <Pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger [%file:%line] %msg%n</Pattern>
  </layout>
 </appender>
 
 <logger name="org.springframework">
  <level value="WARN" />
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
 </logger>

Comment: <root>
  <level value="ERROR" />
  <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
 </root>
</configuration>

Comment: Not the solution i am looking for but a workaround... to remove the warning, i made the number of URIs in xsi:schemaLocation in my applicationContext.xml EVEN... weird.. :)