# How to turn off logs of SAXException in console in Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot

I'm doing a backend using Spring Boot v3.1.1 and JAVA 17. We communicate with other internal services using JAX-RPC with the help of these dependencies:

```
implementation 'wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.3'
implementation 'org.apache.axis:axis:1.4'
implementation 'org.apache.axis:axis-jaxrpc:1.4'
implementation 'org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.2'
```

During development, I didn't encounter any exceptions and all the process was flawless. Now in production, the logs are getting bigger and bigger because of a `org.xml.sax.SAXException`.

```
06-Jul-2023 04:00PM ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.a.c.Call                             : Exception:

org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad types (class java.util.HashMap -> class com.lorem.ws.model.domain.customer.Contract)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCHandler.onStartChild(RPCHandler.java:286) ~[axis-1.4.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035) ~[axis-1.4.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165) ~[axis-1.4.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141) ~[axis-1.4.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236) ~[axis-1.4.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384) ~[axis-1.4.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467) ~[axis-1.4.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366) ~[axis-1.4.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812) ~[axis-1.4.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClientProxy.invoke(AxisClientProxy.java:163) ~[axis-1.4.jar!/:?]
    at jdk.proxy2.$Proxy112.getNetBalance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptorUtils.doInvoke(RmiClientInterceptorUtils.java:101) ~[spring-remoting-1.2.9.jar!/:1.2.9]
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptorUtils.invoke(RmiClientInterceptorUtils.java:74) ~[spring-remoting-1.2.9.jar!/:1.2.9]
    at org.springframework.remoting.jaxrpc.JaxRpcPortClientInterceptor.invoke(JaxRpcPortClientInterceptor.java:504) ~[spring-remoting-1.2.9.jar!/:1.2.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar!/:6.0.10]
    at jdk.proxy2.$Proxy113.getNetBalance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

*I added the lines at the top of the Exception because the whole message is enormous.*

In production I have this settings for the logs:

```
logging.level.root=error
```

The method that is causing the issue is:

```java
private void myCustomFunction(String value) {
    try {
        Balance[] balances = service.getNetBalance(value);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}
}
```

The method `getNetBalance` returns `RemoteException` but I don't do and don't need to do anything if that exception fires.

I have tried to capture the `RemoteException` and print an error log myself:

```java
private void myCustomFunction(String value) {
    try {
        Balance[] balances = service.getNetBalance(value);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage())
    }
}
```

I can see my log being printed, but I also can see the `org.xml.sax.SAXException` anyways and the logs are taking a lot of space.

I have seen these topics as well:

- [How to turn off debug log messages in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353869/how-to-turn-off-debug-log-messages-in-spring-boot)
- [Spring Boot turn off logging for a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634547/spring-boot-turn-off-logging-for-a-package)
- [Turning off Spring warning logs using slf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396828/turning-off-spring-warning-logs-using-slf4j)

None worked for me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

I've tried this:

```
logging.level.org.xml.sax=off
```

After searching a little bit, I have found that the responsible of firing the `org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad types` is a class called `RPCHandler` under the package `org.apache.axis.message`.

Here is its snippet of code:

```java
if (null != xsiClass  && !JavaUtils.isConvertable(xsiClass, destClass)) {
           throw new SAXException("Bad types (" +
                                  xsiClass + " -> " + destClass + ")");
}
```

**How can I turn off that SAXException?** *(avoid its stackTrace of being printed to the console)*

Thanks in advance and I appreciate any push on this one.

Answer (score 0):

After some time trying different things, I have found a solution.

*I don't know if this is the best way, also I'm not sure if this have other implications.*

If we see the logs carefully, especially the line where the logger resides, you will see the class that is printing the message:

```
06-Jul-2023 04:00PM ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.a.c.Call
```

There is a class called `Call` under the `org.apache.axis.client` package. Knowing this, we can do inside `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.apache.axis.client.Call=off
```

Now, I can no longer see the Exception that I was trying to hide in the console, which is what I wanted.